# Detect duplicate files for upload

Tags: javascript, html

I have an `<input type="file" multiple />` and using the `onchange` event I maintain a list of files selected to be uploaded at a later stage. The workflow is like this:

1. The user selects multiple files to upload
2. I copy the selected `File` objects into an array of selected files
3. Repeat steps 1&2 until the user has finished selecting all of the files that they wish to upload.
4. Upload all of the files in the selected array

The problem is that they can potentially end up selecting the same file twice e.g.

1. Select `folder1\a.txt`, click ok
2. Select `folder1\b.txt`, click ok
3. Select `folder1\a.txt`, click ok

The [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) object doesn't give me the full path to the file and `URL.createObjectURL` doesn't return the same URL, so it seems like I can only try to guess that the same file has been selected by comparing the size, last modified time, mime type and file name.

Is there a more accurate way detect if a user is trying to upload the same file multiple times?